# Селект который возвращает X записей из ничего

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Всем привет,
задаюсь вопросом, возможно ли написать селект который будет возвращать X записей из ничего.

Что-то типа такого

```
SELECT rand() AS 'random' LIMIT 10
```

И чтобы возвращал

```
random
------
0.5
2.2
1
0.4
0.1
2
1.4
1.2
3.5
1.1
```

Я знаю что это можно сделать через куча селектов и `union all` но я думаю что не очень хорошее решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT 1 num 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  num + 1 FROM cte WHERE  num < 10
)
SELECT ROUND(RAND() * 5, 1) random
FROM cte;
```